# Eclipse and Google App Engine: ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd; unrecognized arguments: --high_replication

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine

Just upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 and Eclipse complained with the following 2 errors:

```
1. ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd

ERROR    2013-03-25 07:26:43,559 http_runtime.py:221] unexpected port response from runtime ['']; exiting the development server
ERROR    2013-03-25 07:26:43,561 server.py:576] Request to '/_ah/warmup' failed

2. dev_appserver.py: error: unrecognized arguments: --high_replication
```

I've never encountered the first one. And for the second, I used to run google app engine applications by setting the `--high_replication` argument and it worked well. Why all the sudden, these two didn't work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you upgrade to the 1.7.6 SDK?  Some of the commandline parameters changed, I believe high_replication is on by default.

Comment: Yes, the version is 1.7.6. Thanks for clarifying that, dragonx. In addition, do you have any idea about the first error?

Comment: No clue about the first one, it's probably something with your system setup.  I just grepped through the SDK and there's no reference to _sysconfigdata_nd.

Comment: I think that was a bug because if I used `old_dev_appserver.py` instead, everything was fine. I have filed a bug report. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The "No module named _sysconfigdata_nd" is [a bug in the Ubuntu package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1115466).

You can create a softlink as a workaround:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-*/_sysconfigdata_nd.py /usr/lib/python2.7/
```

Comment: Depending on different conditions, updating `virtualenv` may actually be a better idea instead of this walkaround, as mentioned on linked bug reports. To update `virtualenv` you could use the following command: `sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv`.

Answer (score 27):

Depending on different conditions, updating `virtualenv` may actually be a better idea instead of [this walkaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16224441/548696), as mentioned on [linked bug reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1115466). To update `virtualenv` you could use the following command:

```sh
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

Comment: Works like a charm! (Ubuntu 14.04)

Comment: I needed to make the link to upgrade virtualenv, but could remove it afterward.