# Pip install BeautifulSoup4 doesn't work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip

I am guessing this is a isolated problem with my computer but I can't get beautfulsoup4 installed on my Linux machine. I have never had a problem with pip but this one isn't working for me. Easy_install isn't working for me either. I am not very good at reading these log files but here is the one from pip:

```
    ------------------------------------------------------------
/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/bin/pip run on Wed Oct 16 18:32:05 2013
Downloading/unpacking BeautifulSoup4

  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/BeautifulSoup4
  URLs to search for versions for BeautifulSoup4:
  * http://pypi.python.org/simple/BeautifulSoup4/
  Getting page http://pypi.python.org/simple/BeautifulSoup4/
  Analyzing links from page https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/
    Found link https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/beautifulsoup4/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz#md5=b8d157a204d56512a4cc196e53e7d8ee (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.3.2
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.0/beautifulsoup4-4.0.1.tar.gz#md5=115b72374672bc1d5f00dc447c6d8042 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.0.1
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.0/beautifulsoup4-4.0.2.tar.gz#md5=fe530c38449d41d2bbc7103b05865b4b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.0.2
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.0/beautifulsoup4-4.0.3.tar.gz#md5=02c6256a83ed3dfccf563c0511245acf (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.0.3
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.0/beautifulsoup4-4.0.4.tar.gz#md5=49c05ccf28bd3e3893b1d04a93857547 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.0.4
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.0/beautifulsoup4-4.0.5.tar.gz#md5=5f20d3d1cbfd974b71f2c281a34d9645 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.0.5
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.1/beautifulsoup4-4.1.0.tar.gz#md5=bf69362be7d0c32515872f944763658b (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.1.0
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.1/beautifulsoup4-4.1.1.tar.gz#md5=fccee58b4d914fb489385d672fe89f43 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.1.1
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.1/beautifulsoup4-4.1.2.tar.gz#md5=19c63351cd7a94de3453d7753cc87a93 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.1.2
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.1/beautifulsoup4-4.1.3.tar.gz#md5=5aece3c0b8a080658155958111fa2fa9 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.1.3
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.2/beautifulsoup4-4.2.0.tar.gz#md5=3e709c68b7705b49635dca0c551a4362 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.2.0
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.2/beautifulsoup4-4.2.1.tar.gz#md5=91ea70ce16a5f1f43e58f2ef05651679 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.2.1
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.3/beautifulsoup4-4.3.0.tar.gz#md5=95cb572f56e3d679ecc4ce410f7dd447 (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.3.0
    Found link http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/4.3/beautifulsoup4-4.3.1.tar.gz#md5=508095f2784c64114e06856edc1dafed (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/), version: 4.3.1
  Using version 4.3.2 (newest of versions: 4.3.2, 4.3.1, 4.3.0, 4.2.1, 4.2.0, 4.1.3, 4.1.2, 4.1.1, 4.1.0, 4.0.5, 4.0.4, 4.0.3, 4.0.2, 4.0.1)
  Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/b/beautifulsoup4/beautifulsoup4-4.3.2.tar.gz#md5=b8d157a204d56512a4cc196e53e7d8ee (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/beautifulsoup4/)
  Running setup.py egg_info for package BeautifulSoup4

    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found


    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/beautifulsoup4.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/build/BeautifulSoup4 has version 4.3.2, which satisfies requirement BeautifulSoup4
Installing collected packages: BeautifulSoup4

  Running setup.py install for BeautifulSoup4

    Running command /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/build/BeautifulSoup4/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KqaePd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/include/site/python2.7
    running install
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

      File "/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/build/BeautifulSoup4/setup.py", line 27, in <module>

        "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

        dist.run_commands()

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

        self.run_command(cmd)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 971, in run_command

        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized

        self.finalize_options()

      File "/home/croberts/.venvburrito/lib/python/distribute-0.6.32-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 29, in finalize_options

        _install.finalize_options(self)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 321, in finalize_options

        (prefix, exec_prefix) = get_config_vars('prefix', 'exec_prefix')

      File "/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py", line 92, in sysconfig_get_config_vars

        real_vars = old_get_config_vars(*args)

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 489, in get_config_vars

        func()

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 433, in _init_posix

        from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars

      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>

        from _sysconfigdata_nd import *

    ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd

    Complete output from command /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/build/BeautifulSoup4/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KqaePd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/include/site/python2.7:

    running install

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/build/BeautifulSoup4/setup.py", line 27, in <module>

    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 971, in run_command

    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized

    self.finalize_options()

  File "/home/croberts/.venvburrito/lib/python/distribute-0.6.32-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 29, in finalize_options

    _install.finalize_options(self)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 321, in finalize_options

    (prefix, exec_prefix) = get_config_vars('prefix', 'exec_prefix')

  File "/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py", line 92, in sysconfig_get_config_vars

    real_vars = old_get_config_vars(*args)

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 489, in get_config_vars

    func()

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 433, in _init_posix

    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars

  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>

    from _sysconfigdata_nd import *

ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd

----------------------------------------

Command /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/build/BeautifulSoup4/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KqaePd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/build/BeautifulSoup4

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 261, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1166, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 589, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 612, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/build/BeautifulSoup4/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-KqaePd-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --install-headers /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/croberts/.virtualenvs/lunchbox/build/BeautifulSoup4
```

Any ideas on how to fix this would be appreciated. I am kind of new to Python in general so I don't really know what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the errors in your log file it appears that this is causing your issue:

`ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd`

Assuming you are using Ubuntu a possible fix can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16224441/1878708

For more information and other possible fixes see:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1115466