# How to set up a Virtual Environment for makerbot/s3g

Tags: python, virtualenv

I'm trying to get this module working:

https://github.com/makerbot/s3g

Their naming is a bit confusing, as the whole thing often gets referred to as "makerbot_driver" and there is also a subfolder called that.

I run into to trouble when I try to run the command:

```
python virtualenv.py virtualenv
```

When I try to run it in the makerbot_driver folder, as they suggest, I get this:

```
python: can't open file 'virtualenv.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Which makes sense, as virtualenv.py is actually one folder up. However, when I go one folder up, and run the same command, it has a bit more success, but runs into a bunch of errors that I really can't seem to interpret:

```
New python executable in virtualenv/bin/python
Installing setuptools...................................
  Complete output from command /home/jason/GitHub/s3g/virtualenv/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])






" /home/jason/GitHub/s...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 279, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 240, in main
  File "/home/jason/GitHub/s3g/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1712, in main
  File "/home/jason/GitHub/s3g/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1700, in with_ei_usage
  File "/home/jason/GitHub/s3g/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1716, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 971, in run_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/home/jason/GitHub/s3g/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 125, in finalize_options
  File "/home/jason/GitHub/s3g/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1121, in _expand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 312, in get_finalized_command
    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
    self.finalize_options()
  File "/home/jason/GitHub/s3g/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 32, in finalize_options
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/command/install.py", line 321, in finalize_options
    (prefix, exec_prefix) = get_config_vars('prefix', 'exec_prefix')
  File "/home/jason/GitHub/s3g/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.py", line 88, in sysconfig_get_config_vars
    real_vars = old_get_config_vars(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 495, in get_config_vars
    func()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 439, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_nd import *
ImportError: No module named _sysconfigdata_nd
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "virtualenv.py", line 2270, in <module>
    main()
  File "virtualenv.py", line 928, in main
    never_download=options.never_download)
  File "virtualenv.py", line 1040, in create_environment
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "virtualenv.py", line 593, in install_setuptools
    search_dirs=search_dirs, never_download=never_download)
  File "virtualenv.py", line 567, in _install_req
    cwd=cwd)
  File "virtualenv.py", line 1006, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /home/jason/GitHub/s3g/virtualenv/bin/python -c "#!python
\"\"\"Bootstra...sys.argv[1:])






" /home/jason/GitHub/s...ols-0.6c11-py2.7.egg failed with error code 1
```

I've tried to install things like the pyserial module they require and virtualenv, and that's all turned out fine, but this virtualenv thing just keeps going badly for me.

Any advice at all would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The answer can help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608236/eclipse-and-google-app-engine-importerror-no-module-named-sysconfigdata-nd-u

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to use this makerbot projet to set up communication between a raspberry pi and a Replicator Mini, but it appears as though I can't get the serial port of the printer (it works with a Replicator 2X). Which printer are you working with?

Comment: I was using a Replicator 2. My code's available on GitHub, if you'd like it: https://github.com/JujuZA/PiMaker I built  a system to run the makerbot from the raspberry pi and a web service so that you could upload, trigger and monitor prints from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a known bug in Ubuntu. Fix:

```
$ cd /usr/lib/python2.7
$ sudo ln -s plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata_nd.py .
```

Then it works.

```
$ python2.7 virtualenv.py virtualenv
New python executable in virtualenv/bin/python2.7
Not overwriting existing python script virtualenv/bin/python (you must use virtualenv/bin/python2.7)
Installing setuptools................................done.
Installing pip.....................done.
```