# No module named _sysconfigdata_nd

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, virtualenv

This issue came up for me when I installed [Gundo](https://github.com/vim-scripts/Gundo) Vim plugin.

I found many posts about `No module named _sysconfigdata_nd`, but all of them ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16224441/2640636)) refer to [a bug in the Ubuntu package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1115466), and suggest making a symbolic link like this:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-*/_sysconfigdata_nd.py /usr/lib/python2.7/
```

This, however, is not applicable for me, as I'm using Python that I compiled myself.

Per suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20991008/2640636), I did

```
sudo pip install --upgrade virtualenv
```

which created this directory

```
.../lib/python2.7/plat-linux2/
```

but there is no `_sysconfigdata_nd.py` in it.

In my `.../lib/python2.7/` I have `_sysconfigdata.py` but no `_sysconfigdata_nd.py`.

I've not been able to find any further leads.

Comment: This is a useful link to the solution. I had the same problem and I was able to locate the _sysconfigdata_nd.py file in the location "/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-*/" and creating a link might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16224441/9979805

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same problem. I installed anaconda python and by mistake removed stock python. Then `No module named _sysconfigdata_nd` error started coming even though I explicitly pointed `/usr/bin/python` to anaconda python. I also tried all the methods that you have done but failed. So I downloaded stock python from [official source](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/) and installed it. Even after installing python and pointing `/usr/bin/python` to `/usr/bin/python2.7` using `update-alternatives` it started giving me the same error but when I invoke `/usr/bin/python` it works fine so i created an alias for python like this `alias python=/usr/bin/python` and added it to my `.bashrc` file and now it is working fine. I recommend you to try the same. If you want to export the alias `python` globally. You can add it in `/eyc/bin/bash.bashrc` which will be applied to all users by default.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this helped

```
ln -fs /usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu/_sysconfigdata.py /usr/lib/python2.7/
```

credits: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/410